# First-countable topological monoids without local absorbing elements whose topology is induced by a semimetric

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, semigroups-and-monoids, metric-spaces

This is a follow up of [Question 163246](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/163246/if-mathbb-m-tau-is-a-topological-monoid-is-tau-always-induced-by-a-l). For the reader's convenience, let me first copy&paste some basic definitions.

We let a *semimetric* on a set $X$ be a function $d: X \times X \to [0,\infty]$ such that $d(x,x) = 0$ and $d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(y,z)$ for all $x,y,z \in X$. Exactly as with "classical" metrics, $d$ induces a topology on $X$, which we call the *canonical topology* of $d$, having as a base the sets $\{y \in X: d(x,y) < r\}$ as $x$ ranges over $X$ and $r$ over $\mathbf R^+$. We say that a topology $\tau$ on $X$ is *semimetrizable* if there exists a semimetric $d$ on $X$ such that $\tau$ is the canonical topology of $d$.

Next, we take a *topological monoid* to be, as usual, a pair $(\mathbb M, \tau)$ consisting of a (multiplicatively written) monoid $\mathbb M = (M, \cdot)$ and a topology $\tau$ on $M$ such that $\cdot$ is continuous [...] in the expected sense.

Finally, if $\mathbb M = (M, \cdot)$ is a monoid and $d$ is a semimetric on $M$, we say that $d$ is: *right $\mathbb M$-subinvariant* if $d(xz,yz) \le d(x,y)$ for all $x,y,z \in M$; *left* $\mathbb M$-subinvariant if it is right $\mathbb M^{\rm op}$-subinvariant, where $\mathbb M^{\rm op}$ is the dual of $\mathbb M$; and *$\mathbb M$-subinvariant* if it is both right and left $\mathbb M$-subinvariant.

With that said, let $(\mathbb M, \tau)$ be a first-countable topological monoid, with $\mathbb M = (M, \cdot)$. It has been already observed in the [other thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/163246/if-mathbb-m-tau-is-a-topological-monoid-is-tau-always-induced-by-a-l) that $\tau$ does not need be semimetrizable (see Chris Schommer-Pries' construction [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/163535/16537) and the comments to his answer). Furthermore, $\tau$ doesn't need be induced by a left or right subinvariant semimetric even in the case when the topology is metrizable (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/163531/16537)); however, the construction used for proving it does "critically" depend on the fact that $\mathbb M$ has an absorbing element.

Based on the above, we then say that $\mathbb M$ is *resilient* if there doesn't exist any non-trivial submonoid $S$ of $\mathbb M$ [...] with an absorbing element (in particular, this means that the only idempotent element of $\mathbb M$ is the identity). Then here are my questions:

> > **Q1.** If $\mathbb M$ is resilient and $\tau$ is [semi]metrizable, is it true that $\tau$ is the canonical topology of a left (respectively, right) $\mathbb M$-subinvariant semimetric? **Q2.** And what about the case when $\mathbb M$ is, in addition, cancellative (i.e., $xz=yz$ or $zx=zy$ for some $x,y,z \in M$ imply $x=y$)?

Thanks in advance for any comment, hint, pointer, or whatever. (Some parts of the current formulation of the OP are based on comments by Eric Wofsey and Chris Schommer-Pries.)

Comment: A monoid is resilient iff it has no idempotents besides the identity, since any idempotent $i$ is absorbing in the submonoid $\{1,i\}$ and any (locally) absorbing element is idempotent.

Comment: Also, you really want to assume that the topology is semimetrizable, not just that it is first-countable (I don't know whether these are equivalent, but I doubt they are). Chris's construction is quite flexible and can easily be modified to be "resilient".  For instance, you could take $X\coprod\mathbb{N}$, where adding elements of $X$ to anything but $0$ is the same as adding $1$.

Comment: Or take the free commutative monoid generated by X, also resilient, and it contains X as a proper component.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply (I was on holiday). In fact, there're 1st-countable topologies which are not semimetrizable (to be honest, I had no doubt about their existence, but it's only two days ago that I found a counterexample): this is the case, e.g., with the cofinite topology on a countably infinite set. So yes, I restated the OP to take into account your comments.

Comment: I don't see you mentioning $1$ (or $e$). Do you consider monoids or semigroups?

Comment: I'm considering monoids (to me, a monoid is a unital semigroup, or, if you prefer, a unital associative magma in the sense of Bourbaki). But I'm not sure to get the point of your question! What do you mean? Btw, my use of "in addition" in the present formulation of Q2 is misleading: every cancellative monoid is resilient.

Comment: Errata corrige. My "proof" that $(X,\tau)$ isn't semimetrizable when $X$ is countably infinite and $\tau$ is the cofinite topology on $X$ was flawed, and in fact, the contrary is true! This follows from a (straightforward) generalization of a theorem by W. A. Wilson dating back to the 1930s, which appears, e.g., as Theorem 6.3.50 in J. Goubault-Larrecq, _Non-Hausdorff Topology and Domain Theory: Selected Topics in Point-Set Topology_ (New Math. Monographs 22, Cambridge Univ. Press, 2013), or can be recovered as an instance of a theorem by A. H. Frink on countably-based quasi-uniformities [...]

Comment: [...] (see _Distance function and the metrization problem_, BAMS 43 (1937), 133-142). However, it is still true that not all first-countable topologies are semimetrizable, and I learned from R. Fox' work that the question is related to the $\gamma$-space problem (every semimetrizable space is a $\gamma$-space, and it took some time before a disproof of the converse). A Hausdorff counterexample is, in fact, given in: R. Fox, _Solution of the $\gamma$-space problem_, Proc. AMS 85 (1982), 606-608. And H.-P. A. Künzi, in his survey "Nonsymmetric distances and their associated topologies: [...]

Comment: [...] About the origins of basic ideas in the area of asymmetric topology'' (in C. E. Aull and R. Lowen (eds.), _Handbook of the History of General Topology, Vol. 3_, Dordrecht: Kluwer (2001), 853-968), reports a letter by the same Fox where even a paracompact Hausdorff counterexample (to the $\gamma$-space conjecture) is provided.